# wordpress installation on vm instance on compute engine on google cloud - file permission errors

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform

I have been asked to look at a wordpress site that is on google cloud - the Wordpress admin works fine - the front end of the site doesn't show the css

I believe it to be a file permission issue

Replicating the site and placing it on a different server with correct wordpress file permissions it works fine.

However on google cloud I have issues with trying to change the file permissions.

I have ftp access using Filezilla but can't change file permissions that way and if I try to use the apache ssh console to change file permissions that wont apply either.

So looking at the owner of the folder var/www/html and the group it is showing as www-data not root - so first question is what should be the correct owner and group ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a file system permission problem instead of an Apache configuration problem?

Comment: no John not sure. I eliminated the wordpress issue by duplicating the site and hosting it elsewhere and it working. So the inability of being Able to change the file permissions is where it looks to be an issue on google cloud. As it wasn't my initial work I wasn't clear what has been done on the vm instance before I was asked to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change folder & file permissions and ownership do the following.

SSH into the VM, google cloud provide a SSH browser based terminal.

SSH will open a linux terminal, if you are root user no need to type 'sudo' for the following commands.

Type 'sudo vim /etc/apache2/envvars'

read what the config file says, defaults are:
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

Exit the config file back to the linux terminal command line.

Type the following commands to give Apache appropriate User and Group permissions in the public wordpress directory, change user and group name as appropriate

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

sudo find /var/www/html  -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;

sudo find /var/www/html  -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

You can now exit the SSH terminal. Note if you want to see the new permissions in FileZilla press F5 to refresh FileZilla.

Comment: thank you MikeMoy,, so what directories should the www-data user and owner have access to

Comment: what part of my original answer do you not understand ?

Comment: Hi MikeMoy I get the error: find missing arguament to "-exec" when I try to run sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 750 {} ;

Comment: type it in manually instead of copy and pasting it

Comment: stackoverflow was automatically removing one of the characters when written as plain text

Comment: ok have run and now when trying to use Filezilla I get:Command: cd "/var/www/html"
Error: Directory /var/www/html: permission denied
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: ny suggestions?]

Comment: The user nane you are you logging in as with filezilla does not have the execute permission on the folder you are trying to open.  I usually log in as user name root with filezilla so that i have access to everything on the server.

Comment: thank you Mike - so the private key I made to set the google cloud connection needs changing?

Comment: You don't add private keys to Google cloud,  you add public keys to Google Cloud. Then configure filezilla to access your server with the private key

Comment: You can add multiple public keys to Google cloud